# Erro de permissão GULPFILE

Tags: ionic, file-permission

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estava pedindo para eu atualizar meu CLI.

- Atualizei meu ionic;
- Tentei atualizar meu ionic lib e deu erro e agora não consigo acessar meu aplicativo.

Comment: Já tentou dar permissão a esse arquivo ?

Comment: Eu dei permissão pra toda a pasta mas parece que ele recria este arquivo toda vez que compila. Porque se toda a pasta ta com permissão desde o .config era pra este arquivo estar acessível não é? @1fabiopereira

Comment: O correto seria o arquivo estar com permissão, mas só para desencargo de conciência tenta das duas maneiras atribuindo permissão a toda pasta com: sudo chmod 777 -R /home/henrique/.config se caso isso não resolver tente sudo chmod 777  /home/henrique/.config/configstore/bower-github.json

Comment: @1fabiopereira mas eu uso o este comando antes do diretório .config ou ou nele mesmo da certo? de qualquer forma vou tentar aqui.

Comment: Obteve algum resultado?